# FLTK layout management

Tags: c++, fltk

Is there any more tutorials on how to layout fltk gui than http://fltk.org/articles.php?L415+I20+T+P1+Qresize ? Seems a bit hard to layout this way anyone with any tips on how to do this manually or is fluid the only option?

BRG Anders Olme

Comment: "How to layout fltk gui" has nothing to do with the tutorial you pasted. Yes, the most appropriate way to create GUI layout is FLUID rather than banging your head with manually writing code. Or might be I couldn't understand what you asked.

Comment: FLTK 1.4 is the active branch. Don't use 2.0 anymore. 1.4 master/daily includes Fl_Flex which allows for easy horizontal and vertical layouts. More to come soon. I also highly recommend FLUID, the interface designer that comes with FLTK. It has a preview function to try out the layout and resizing behaviour while designing a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no other articles about it that I know of.
For the manual layout, check this link: http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/classfltk_1_1Widget.html#aa69b28a41fdd0674cbb85a6a57ee52c8 .

Btw, there is a guy on our [FLTK IRC channel](http://tinyurl.com/7zewo2w) (#FLTK on the OFTC IRC network) who implemented layout manager a-la Java SWING's `FlowLayout` and `BoxLayout`.

Comment: PS. they `layout()` explained in the link above is the same in FLTK1 and the upcoming FLTK3.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI for FLTK 1.3*  is fluid. fltk 2.* is dead.
 This site is were I learned to use FLUID:
http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk-videos/

Answer (score 0):

FLTK layout made easier with the header files here: https://fltk-layout-manager.blogspot.com

```
CoordinateManager().set(addrSubject)
   .leftTo (DIRECTION d, void* addrBenefactor, bool stretch = false)
   .rightTo (DIRECTION d, void* addrBenefactor, bool stretch = false)
   .topTo (DIRECTION d, void* addrBenefactor, bool stretch = false)
   .bottomTo (DIRECTION d, void* addrBenefactor, bool stretch = false)

   .centerTo (void* addrBenefactor)
   .centerTo (int x, int y, int x2 = 0, int y2 = 0)

   .leftTo (int x, bool stretch = false)
   .rightTo (int x, bool stretch = false)
   .topTo (int y, bool stretch = false)
   .bottomTo (int y, bool stretch = false)
   
.set(addrBenefactor)
   .leftBy (int n, bool stretch = false)
   .rightBy (int n, bool stretch = false)
   .topBy (int n, bool stretch = false)
   .bottomBy (int n, bool stretch = false)
   
   .render();
```