# Centered Widget in FLTK

Tags: resize, centering, fltk

Can you center a non-resizable widget in FLTK?  The references from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420008/fltk-layout-management) seem to imply the answer is no.  A centered widget would require resizable widgets on either side, but you can only have one resizable child in a group.

(Sorry for the ask and answer, but I searched all over for this and almost gave up, so I think this will be useful to others.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it.  The trick is that a widget in FLTK can be **outside** its parent group's borders.

You have 4 groups A, B, C, and D.  B and C are children of A.  D is a child of C.  Not shown is the widget you actually want to have centered, called E.  E is a child of C.  A and E are the ones you want to actually see.  B, C, and D are empty with no border, so they are invisible.  A and D are resizable.  Nothing else is.  Center E in A, not overlapping with D.  E will be partially outside of C.  That's the trick.

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|                 A                          |
||--------------------||--------------------||
||                    ||           |-----|  ||
||          B         ||      C    |  D  |  ||
||                    ||           |-----|  ||
||--------------------||--------------------||
|--------------------------------------------|
```

When A is resized, B and C will be resized proportionally and equally, because there are no resizable children of A, and they are the same size.  The origin of C will remain in the center of A.  When C is resized, E will not be resized, only D.  So E will remain in the same position with respect to the origin of C, i.e. with respect to the center of A.

*Caveat 1*: I have implemented this in FLUID/FLTK 1.3.0, which is admittedly old.  Things may have changed since then.  I did not attempt to verify this on anything more recent.

*Caveat 2*: FLUID will automatically resize a group to enclose the widgets within it whenever you move **any** widget.  This breaks the centering behavior.  I have found I need to resize C via the FLUID dialog box to the original size, **after** any other layout changes, every time.

Comment: FLTK 1.4 features Fl_Flex in the master branch and dailies since September. This is exactly one of the things that Fl_Flex makes easy.

Answer (score 0):

FLTK layout made easier with the header files here: https://fltk-layout-manager.blogspot.com

```
CoordinateManager()
   .set(addrSubject)
   .centerTo (void* addrBenefactor)
   .render();
```

You can give a point x, y or the top left and bottom right coordinates:

```
CoordinateManager()
   .set(addrSubject)
   .centerTo (int x, int y, int x2 = 0, int y2 = 0)
   .render();
```